# Extent report not marking my tests FAIL, if test failed due to NoSuchElementException or any other exception

Tags: testng, selenium-extent-report

I have used extent report for generating HTML reports, I am using a testing framework. I have only class and have mentioned all of my tests under @Test method of testing. Now if any of my tests are throwing NoSuchElementException then it should be marked as FAIL in extent report and also in testing build status, failed test count should come for this failed test.

I am using try catch for each of my tests and I tried using below in catch
test.fail(e);
extent.flush();

I was expecting that extent report should show failed test as FAIL and also testing build status should show failed test count.

but it didn't happen like this

Answer (score 1):

```
I found the answer and thus posting it.
Use below code in all tests...you must include all test in try catch 

catch (AssertionError e) 
{
            test.fail(e);
            Assert.fail();
            extent.flush();
}

after this any kind of exception that comes in between steps of tests will be caught in catch and then this test.fail will tell extent report to mark that test as FAIL and this Assert.fail() will test TestNG to mark that test as FAIL.

Do include AssertionError in catch block as that is the key which worked for me
```

Comment: I am running into this using Junit5, but this cannot be correct.  What a hacky workaround.   Someone must have the actual real answer to this.